# novalidate attribute to specific field or to entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i set "novalidate" attribute to entire page in the page there are several forms? is this works also for input that are outside form section?

can i set novalidate directly to the input field?

I already tried to set the following attribute in the input field:

```
<input type="text" ... novalidate>
```

and

```
<input type="text" .. formnovalidate="formnovalidate">
```

doesn't works!

Can i set the html attribute in any other container?

Comment: The novalidate attribute can only be used on the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, novalidate property is specific to form elements. So no, you cannot set novalidate automagically to all forms in your page. But you can use a small piece of javascript code to do that for you.

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].setAttribute('novalidate', true);
}
```

Take a look at [this example that I made](http://codepen.io/bruno_krebs/pen/mOwRYd).

Answer (score 1):

there are minor difference between novalidate and formnovalidate.
novalidate is applied to the form, and prevents it from being validated; formnovalidate is applied to a submit button, and overrides the novalidate option, if present; it means 'submit this form without validating.

you can use this kind of attribute when you don't require validation to be saved. because the data might be incomplete and invalid,